# What is my AWS SCP preventing creation of any EC2 instances even with the correct tag key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to apply an AWS Service Control Policy that prevents the creation of an EC2 instance unless a specific tag is provided in the request.

Why is the following SCP denying the creation of an EC2 instance (with an ENI & EBS volume) under, from what I can tell, all circumstances, even if I provide the required tag? (FYI, I am creating the instance from the AWS Console and am adding the tag in the request.) Without this policy applied, I am able to create the instance successfully.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RequireEnvironmentTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": "sc:environment"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SCP you're providing has `Resource` set to `*`, which is preventing the creation of your ENI ([`network-interface`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-resources-for-iam-policies)).

Set the resource to specific [supported resource types defined by Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-resources-for-iam-policies) to fix the issue.

For example, the below SCP should only allow EC2 *instances* with the tag key of `sc:environment` to be created.

I also assume you are specifying `ec2:CreateTags` as an action to block modification of tags after they've been set as `ec2:CreateTags` is evaluated for modifying existing tags as well as creating new ones (they should probably rename the action).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RequireEnvironmentTag",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ]
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": "sc:environment"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, the Resource was the problem. Reviewing here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html it appears that the "network-interface" resource does not support the `aws:TagKeys` condition. When using a `ec2:RunInstance` it is creating an EC2 instance, a EBS volume, and an ENI. So, I think it is the inclusion of the `network-interface` resource that breaks this.

Comment: Wonderful! Yes that's 100% the reason if you are also attaching an ENI :) feel free to update the question with that info and I can make my answer more focused as opposed to "not sure" :)